# Add tags to every span of application using spring sleuth

Tags: spring-boot, trace, open-telemetry, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to add some tags to all of my traces going though my application. I tried without success to extends the DefaultMessageSpanCustomizer as showed in the docs like

```java
@Component
class SpanCustomizerConfig extends DefaultMessageSpanCustomizer {

  @Value("${spring.application.name}")
  private String appName;

  @Override
  public Span customizeHandle(
      final Span spanCustomizer, final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel messageChannel) {
    return super.customizeHandle(spanCustomizer, message, messageChannel)
        .tag("app", this.appName)
        .tag("container", this.appName)
        .tag("component", "api")
        .tag("channelName", this.channelName(messageChannel));
  }

  @Override
  public Span.Builder customizeSend(
      final Span.Builder builder, final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel messageChannel) {
    return super.customizeSend(builder, message, messageChannel)
        .tag("app", this.appName)
        .tag("container", this.appName)
        .tag("component", "api")
        .tag("channelName", this.channelName(messageChannel));
  }
}
```

But unfortunately I could not make it work. Does anyone had success trying to add some tags for every application trace ?

[image]

Thanks a lot for the help.

Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sleuth with Brave (default option) you can register your own `SpanHandler` in the following way to add a tag to every span

```
@Bean
SpanHandler mySpanHandler() {
    return new SpanHandler() {
        @Override
    
        public boolean end(TraceContext context, MutableSpan span, Cause cause) {
            span.tag("add this tag", "for every span");
            return super.end(context, span, cause);
        }
    };
}
```

If you're using Spring Cloud Sleuth OTel please register a bean of type `SpanExporter` and mutate the span. You can check https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel/blob/v1.1.0-M4/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/otel/bridge/ArrayListSpanProcessor.java for reference. You'll need to override the `onStart` method where you have access to `ReadWriteSpan`. There you can modify all of your spans whenever they are started

Comment: Unfortunately I used the spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure.